# 2016 Outlook has error message Required file chart.dll not found in your path Outlook Crashes

Tags: outlook, runtime-error, office365, office-2016

[image]
Since installing Office 2016, Outlook will not operate.  Click on 'new email' (or doing just about anything) and this dialog box pops up...

[image]

Outlook then shuts down and tries to reopen and gets into a loop of freezing...
All other Office programs work fine.
Looking online I've tried these fixes...
I tried to install the chart program with this .dll file and that didn't remove the error.
I don't have the .net framework installed.
I tried to uninstall Office 2016 and then reinstall numerous times: still no success.
I'm using Windows 10, desktop PC.  Office 2013 worked fine and I wish I could go back to it!

Tried in Outlook safe mode by clicking Ctrl+Outlook icon, its still throwing error

Comment: This is not a programming related question - perhaps a stackexhange site like superuser is what you're looking for rather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only folder I found in C:\ that contained "chart.dll" is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16 (for Office 2016 version, may be Office15/14.. for previous versions). I added that folder path to my $PATH variable in Windows and I have not had the error yet although it has only been a few hours..

To do this on Win 10:

- right click Computer/My Computer
- click properties
- click advanced system setting
- advanced tab
- click environment variables

  - modify the "Path"
    environment variable under system variables section-
  - append or add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16" to the Path and save

(you may want do do a search of C:\ for chart.dll and make sure that this is the right path for your situation)